# Распределение памяти

Tags: c++, память, списки

Нужно написать что-то наподобие malloc'a. Свободные области памяти являются списком, а его первый элемент - это и есть память. Эту память нужно задать динамическим массивом и больше нельзя использовать системный malloc.

Скажите правильный ли у меня алгоритм или нет?

1. Создадим список и динамический массив char, к примеру, на 1000 элементов
2. Поместим в первый элемент списка наш дин. массив.
3. Создадим функцию malloc, которая работает так: вводим количество памяти, которое необходимо выделить. Пробегаемся по нашему списку и ищем свободные области памяти, если не нашлось необходимого количества, то берем память из дин.массива. В конце просто переписываем остаток и перебрасываем указатели списка.

И еще вопрос: при выделении памяти я должен как-то учитывать размер списка(я вычитаю `sizeof(list)`)

Comment: Посмотрите как устроены MCB в DOS, например. Всё гораздо проще :)

Comment: На эту тему мне понравилась [эта статья](https://molecularmusings.wordpress.com/2011/07/05/memory-system-part-1/).

Comment: В сети есть несколько статей по реализации разной степени сложности. Что-то быстро мне не попалолсь одно хорошее руководство из MIT, но [вот эта](http://danluu.com/malloc-tutorial/) статья (на первый взгляд) выглядит тоже вполне достойно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Таки залил свою версию распределятора памяти: [mpool.h](https://github.com/klopp/klib/blob/master/mpool.h), [mpool.c](https://github.com/klopp/klib/blob/master/mpool.c). Всё находится в одном монолитном фрагменте - и распределяемая память, и управляющие структуры, никаких дополнительных списков и т.д.

Есть стратегия выбора подходящего свободного блока памяти для распределения, разбиение блоков на занятый и свободный при необходимости, дефрагментация (то есть при неудачной попытке выделения происходит слияние всех соседних свободных блоков и повторная попытка).

Всё удовольствие - пара страниц кода размашистым почерком на чистом C.

Писалось очень давно, под систему, в которой память, разрешённую для динамического выделения, нужно было захватывать сразу после запуска, и все манипуляции проводить только в ней, без использования `malloc()`.

**UPD** Ну зачем я полез в этот код :) Сразу захотелось поулучшать. В результате добавил такое: при нехватке памяти в исходном буфере он может растягиваться (если такое поведение задано при создании). Сохраняя при этом структуру и все данные. Первоначальной идее это может и противоречит, но может оказаться полезно там, где много-много мелких `malloc()/free()` сильно фрагментируют память.

Comment: Живительный рефакторинг — наше всё!

Comment: @klopp А как вообще в такой программе (т.е. в реализации таких своих "аллокаторов") оценить производительность и степень фрагментации?

Comment: Ну, производительность оценить легко - обычными бенчмарками по выделению/освобождению случайных кусков памяти. Много раз и в 2 прохода: с malloc/free (new/delete) и своим. На одних и тех же наборах, конечно. А фрагментация... Там, для чего это делалось, такие вещи оценивались на системном уровне (novell netware server 20-летней давности). Вот, кстати, очень неплохая статья Кунта про всё это: http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/331012/

Comment: *Живительный рефакторинг — наше всё!* а ещё есть хорошее правило "работает - не трогай' :-) Вот поленился тесты через valgrind прогнать - тут же косяк пропустил в новом коде. Поправил уже.

Answer (score 1):

В общем правильно. Но для хипа надо сразу и удаление продумывать, то есть то как запоминать какие куски были выделены чтобы их корректно освобождать потом.